# iOS AJAX Upload image not working

Tags: ios, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have the following code to upload an image from the browser:

```
    var PageID = $("[id*=hdnfldPageID]").val();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("UploadedFile_" + CraftItemId + "_" + PageID, files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UploadFile.ashx",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        data: data,
        success: function (updated) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    });
```

On iPhone 6S Plus and iPad Air 10.2.1 it just gets stuck and does not succeed nor fail. I've tried it on both Safari and Chrome.

On Android it's working fine.

I can't figure out the issue